RE: Built In Terrariums
Back again!
Hi, I've decided to add context to this question and my previous oneby providing how I'd think the environment would work, as well as the relationship between the host and terrarium inhabitant.
Nursery Nymphs
A species of animals that have evolved to have transparent 'nursery' like stomachs that hold plants and animals inside of them.
Their stomachs grew to be transparent through the thinning of skin in order to attract mates as well as find a way to camouflage with their environment.
They have a symbiotic relationship with these plants and animals, where they provide a home and food for the terrarium inhabitant, while the terrarium inhabitant provides energy for the host.
To protect the internal organs it establishes a clear window of skin on the outerside of the organs
The terrarium inhabitant helps break down food.
The terrarium also displays health and vitality, attracting mates.
These nymphs are bipedal as a way for advantage.
This is honestly just a silly species idea for a world but I really like it so far! Please tell me if this makes sense :)

I'm not putting this as an answer because it is so short. If I read your character explanation just like you wrote it in a book, I wouldn't flinch. Made perfect sense to me. The only thing I'm asking myself is "How strong can skin so thin it looks transparent be ?"

@or4ng3h4t Think spider webbing! Or a thin layer of plexiglass :)

Do the nymphs have any natural predators? Because running around with a terrarium in your abdomen is probably closer to running "with a hamster in your backpack" than running "while pregnant", which would be very rough on the organisms inside unless the pets are nothing bigger than insects.

@DotCounter yes!! They are their own predators due to the subspecies hierarchy:) I probably should've mentioned this, but there is a hierarchy of: plant < bug < beast < amphibian < reptile < marine

The format of this site (and the sites on this "network") is that each Question is a complete page to itself, with its own answers - you can't "reply to" another Question, as implied by the "RE:" in your title. On the other hand, you can [edit] a Question; so that's what people meant when they asked you to "clarify your question". You might want to take a moment to look at the [tour] and [help] to get a better idea of the site's mechanics and rules.

Please edit your previous question instead of creating another post that clarifies the first without clearly asking a separate question. We have a strict one question per post policy. Usually people run afowl of this by asking multiple questions but in this case your post fails to ask a question.

Does this answer your question? Could a Creature Evolve to have a BUILT IN terrarium/nursery

I’m voting to close this question because, frankly, I can't find a question. Stack Exchange's purpose is to seek help resolving specific problems. The goals, expectations and limits of the service can be found via the [tour] (where you'll learn SE is not a discussion forum) and the following two Help Center pages: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]. Is the idea cool? Sure! But that's not an acceptable reason to post on Stack Exchange. Do you have a specific problem you need help resolving?
